# How to import all "our"-variables from the unnamed Perl module without listing them?

Tags: perl, import, module, global-variables

I need to import all **our** variables from the **unnamed** Perl module (Module.pm) and use them inside the Perl script (Script.pl).

The following code works well without the **"use strict"**, but failed with it. How can I change this code to work with **"use strict"** without the manual listing of all imported variables (as described in the answer to [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109581/how-can-i-share-global-values-among-different-packages-in-perl))?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Script.pl:

```
use strict;
require Module;
print $Var1;
```

Module.pm:

```
our $Var1 = "1\n";
...
our $VarN = "N\n";
return 1;
```

Run the script:

```
$> perl Script.pl
```

Errors:

```
Global symbol "$Var1" requires explicit package name at Script.pl line 3.
Execution of Script.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

**NOTE (1)**: The module is unnamed, so using a `Module::` prefix is not the option.

**NOTE (2)**: `Module.pm` contains also a set of functions configured by global variables.

**NOTE (3)**: Variables are different and should NOT be stored in one array.

**NOTE (4)**: Design is NOT good, but the question is not about the design. It's about forcing of the listed code to work with minimal modifications with the complexity `O(1)`, i.e. a few lines of code that don't depend on the `N`.

**Solution Candidate (ACCEPTED)**: Add `$::` before all imported variables. It's compliant with `strict` and also allows to differ `my` variables from `imported` in the code.

Comment: If you need to subvert `use strict` then you're better off just not using strict.

Comment: @evil otto - I need **strict** to catch other problems in the program.

Comment: If you're exporting 1000 variables, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @ikegami - The number is about 50 indeed.

Comment: Same goes for 50. In fact, exporting *any* variables is usually suboptimal.

Comment: @ikegami - fully agree. But this module is internal and has a most appropriate architecture in our project for now.

Comment: @ikegami - The design is not so bad, though. It's just a number of functions configured by a number of global variables instead of parameters. The number of variables can be very big dependent on the problem area solved by the module (variables are completely different and cannot be organized into one hash).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your script to:

```
use strict;
require Module;
print $Module::Var1;
```

The problem is the `$Var1` isn't in the main namespace, it's in `Module`'s namespace.

**Edit:** As is pointed out in comments below, you haven't named your module (i.e. it doesn't say `package Module;` at the top). Because of this, there is no `Module` namespace. Changing your script to:

```
use strict;
require Module;
print $main::Var1;
```

...allows the script to correctly print out `1\n`.

Comment: Since `$Var1` is in an "unnamed" module, as the OP calls it, it is in the `main` namespace. Access with `$main::Var1` or even just `$::Var1` to be compliant with `strict`.

Comment: @aponomarenko: I've edited the answer to reflect mob's comment. The script, as edited, now works as you'd expect with your 'unnamed' module.

Comment: Is there a way to not to add **$main::** or **$::** everywhere for each variable? Something like the alias from **$main::VarN** to **$VarN**?

Comment: @aponomarenko: Not unless you can edit `Module.pm` to be a proper module, then export all of the variables you want to export.

Comment: @CanSpice - I want to export all of them. Is it possible to use some "internal" Perl function to import them all, but not to list them manually? Something like the function **A** that returns a list of global variables declared in the module and a function **B** that imports the variable by name, so I can write: `foreach my $Var (A(Module)) {B($Var);}`?

Answer (score 4):

If you have to import all the **our** variables in every module, there's something seriously wrong with your design.  I suggest that you redesign your program to separate the elements so there is a minimum of cross-talk between them.  This is called [decoupling](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Decoupling#Software_Development).

Comment: Yes, but, unfortunately, it is too late to redesign the code. I need to separate internal modules from one very BIG script (20.000 lines) and minimize the regression, because it is in production about 2 years.

Comment: The design is not so bad, though. It's just a number of functions configured by a number of global variables instead of parameters.

Answer (score 2):

You want to export all variables from a module, and you want to do it in such a way that you don't even know what you're exporting? Forget about `use strict` and `use warnings` because if you put them in your program, they'll just run screaming out, and curl up in a corner weeping hysterically.

I never, and I don't mean hardly ever, never export variables. I always create a method to pull out the required value. It gives me vital control over what I'm exposing to the outside world and it keeps the user's namespace pure.

Let's look at the possible problems with your idea.

1. You have no idea what is being exported in your module. How is the program that uses that module going to know what to use? Somewhere, you have to document that the variable `$foo` and `@bar` are available for use. If you have to do that, why not simply play it safe?
2. You have the issue of someone changing the module, and suddenly a new variable is being exported into the program using that module. Imagine if that variable was already in use. The program suddenly has a bug, and you'll never be able to figure it out.
3. You are exporting a variable in your module, and the developer decides to modify that variable, or even removes it from the program. Again, because you have no idea what is being imported or exported, there's no way of knowing why a bug suddenly appeared in the program.

As I mentioned, you ***have*** to know somewhere what is being used in your module that the program can use, so you have to document it anyway. If you're going to insist on importing variables, at least use the `EXPORT_OK` array and the Exporter module. That will help limit the damage. This way, your program can declare what variables its depending upon and your module can declare what variables it knows programs might be using. If I am modifying the module, I would be extra careful of any variable I see I am exporting. And, if you must specify in your program what variables you're importing, you know to be cautious about those particular variables.

Otherwise, why bother with modules? Why not simply go back to Perl 3.0 and use `require` instead of `use` and forget about using the `package` statement.

Comment: The design is not good, but the question is not about a design. And I'm using `require` without a `package` statement as described in the question. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have data in a file and are trying to load that data into your program.

As it is now, the `our` declarations in the module only declare variables for the scope of that file.  Once the file finshes running, to access the variables, you need to use their fully qualified name.  If your module has a `package xyz;` line, then the fully qualified name is `$xzy::Var1`.  If there is no `package` declaration, then the default package `main` is used, giving your variables the name `$main::Var1`

However, any time that you are making many variables all with numeric name changes, you probably should be using an array.

Change your module to something like:

```
@My::Module::Data = ("1\n", "2\n" ... )
```

and then access the items by index:

```
$My::Module::Data[1]
```

Comment: The module contains data and functions using this data. Variables have different names, so cannot be accessed by the index (of course, they can be rewritten as one hash with different string indexes, but this is not an option for me). Is it possible to alias all $main::VarN to VarN at once?

Comment: The **main** is the built-in namespace. Why I need to explicitly select it? Is there a way to choose a default namespace for script and avoid writing $main:: before each variable?

Comment: `main::` is the built-in namespace, and it is available to you by default.  The only thing forcing you to write it is the `strict` pragma, which requires variables to either be imported from another package, declared with `my` or `our` or fully qualified.  You can abreviate `main::` as `::`, making your variable names `$::Var1`.  There are "ways" of searching for the variables in your module and writing code to "import" them into the calling module, but none of them are particularly robust which is why I hesitate to post one.